# how to exit php code after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to exit my php code after 10 seconds. Is there  any possible way to do that? I have already found this code but it's not working.

```
set_time_limit(10);  *//this line is blocked from the server*
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
```

Comment: Actually your question is pretty vague. What you actually want to do once it get exited?

Comment: Can you add more context please? Why do you want to limit the execution time?

Comment: Do you really want the script to just timeout after 10 sec? Feels like there might be a design flaw buried somewhere here.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Did you just want to left your php page after every 10 seconds or you want to set max time limit for execution?

Comment: How you would be sure that it has been done what was intended to be done by that code?

Answer (score 5):

Did you put `set_time_limit` at the begining of the script? if not - do it, because if you look at official documentation you will see next:

> When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero.
>   In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
>   seconds into script execution a call such as `set_time_limit(20)` is
>   made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing
>   out.

Also check it's return value:
"Returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure."

PS:
"The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real."

Does it help?

All written above you can find in http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 2):

I think that this code may help you:

```
$starttime = time();

do{
    //make something
}
while ((time() - $starttime)<5); //stop with 5 seconds
```